# On-click event on an unbound control in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to modify a sample by Roggers [here](http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/topic84.html) for my project to browse multiple images in MS Access form.

But, I would like to know how I can add an on-click event for the image control to open a details form.

The code behind the form is as follows:

```
    Private Sub P_FillControls()
On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    Dim Cnt As Long

    Cnt = 1
    Do Until (Cnt > BlockSize Or rst.EOF)
        P_SetValues Cnt

        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    If Cnt <= BlockSize Then
        For Cnt = Cnt To BlockSize
            P_SetNulls Cnt
        Next
    End If

ExitPoint:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitPoint
End Sub

Private Sub P_SetValues(Cnt As Long)
On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    If RecCount > 0 Then
        Me("Rn_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).Caption = (rst.AbsolutePosition + 1)
    Else
        Me("Rn_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).Caption = ""
    End If

    Me("Lb_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).Caption = Nz(rst.Fields("ImageName"), "")
    Me("Im_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).Picture = Nz(rst.Fields("ImageFile"), "")
    Me("ID_" & Format(Cnt, "00")) = rst.Fields("ImageFile")

    ' Note - For no caption, dot is used in lieu of
    '            zero length string, so as to prevent the
    '            label from disappearing

ExitPoint:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitPoint
End Sub

Private Sub P_SetNulls(Cnt As Long)
On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    Me("Rn_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).Caption = "."
    Me("Lb_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).Caption = "."
    Me("Im_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).Picture = "."
    Me("ID_" & Format(Cnt, "00")) = Null

    ' Note - For no caption, dot is used in lieu of
    '            zero length string, so as to prevent the
    '            label from disappearing

ExitPoint:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitPoint
End Sub

Public Sub P_Initialize()
    On Error Resume Next

    RecCount = 0    ' Default
    Me.LbNoImage.Visible = False

    ' Remove any existing instance of the recordset
    If Not rst Is Nothing Then
        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
    End If

    ' This recordset will finally get closed in form's
    ' close event.

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Q_ImageNormalSort")
   ' Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Q_Dynamic_Query")

    If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
        ' There are no records
        P_FillControls
        Me.LbNoImage.Visible = True
        P_SetStatusNavBtns
        Me.CmdAdd.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    rst.MoveLast
    RecCount = rst.RecordCount
    LastID = rst.Fields("ImageFile")
    rst.MoveFirst
    FirstID = rst.Fields("ImageFile")

    ' First Load (signified by step size argument = 0)
    P_Next 0

    Me.LbRecMsg.Caption = "Of  " & RecCount

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

In the sample, "Im_" is the control that holds the image on the form.

I will appreciate your help.

Joseph

Comment: Please check that image control have event or not. if yes then look for clicj event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following Sub in your code somewhere at the bottom:

```
Function OpenMyForm(strFormName As String)
    DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName
End Function
```

Stick this in your code below where you set the image:

```
Me("Im_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).OnClick = "=OpenMyForm('F_Details')"
```

Comment: Hi Johnny, With your suggestion at first I was getting a syntax error then I closed the form name with blackets. But still I am getting an error : Expected Function or Variable.

Comment: Did you edit "YourFormName" to be the actual name of the form you want to open?

Comment: Yes Johnny: Me("Im_" & Format(Cnt, "00")).OnClick = DoCmd.OpenForm("F_Details")

Comment: @user1868306 - See my edit.  I tried this with an image with a static name and it worked perfectly, your dynamically named image shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: I am getting same details for any one of the images I click on.

Comment: But F_Details is popping up?  My guess is you need to change the recordset of the form based on which image you're choosing.  Maybe add Forms(strFormName).RecordSource = "SomeRecordSource" or something?  It would go in the OpenMyForm function under the OpenForm line.  You might have to pass a variable into that function that you can use to filter the data?

Comment: Thanx alot Johnny. You've been so wonderful. I will try your suggestion. Stay well.