# Function to determine and pass value in a form control

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a function that will determine the value held in an active form control and then pass the value for a form criteria as follows:

```
Public Function fc_id() As Long

    fc_id = (Screen.ActiveControl.Caption)

End Function

Public Sub sShowForm()

DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Details", , , "c_id = " & fc_id

End Sub
```

I then call the function from the form control being clicked:

```
sShowForm
```

The details form opens but it's black, and there is not error message.

If I use a numeric value, what would be the equivalence of the

> (Screen.ActiveControl.Caption)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily change your procedure to find out what you're getting from `Screen.ActiveControl`:

```vb
Public Sub sShowForm()
    'DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Details", , , "c_id = " & fc_id
    MsgBox Screen.ActiveControl.Name
End Sub
```

You may not be getting what you expect.  For example, if you're using a command button to run `sShowForm()`, the command button is the `ActiveControl`. Whether or not that is the situation, check to see what you're actually getting.

If the present form (the form where your VBA code is running) includes a text box bound to a `c_id` field in the form's record source, you can eliminate the function and reference that text box directly in the `OpenForm` option.  For example, if `c_id` is a numeric field and the text box is named `txtc_id` ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Details", , , "c_id = " & Me.txtc_id
```

If `c_id` is text type, add quotes around the text box value ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Details", , , "c_id = '" & Me.txtc_id & "'"
```

Comment: Hi HansUp. Actually, that's the thing; the textbox is not bound to the form's record source. I am trying to resolve an outsanding issue from my previous post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771577/on-click-event-on-an-unbound-control-in-ms-access?rq=1.

Comment: Hi HansUp. Actually, that's the thing; the textbox is not bound to the form's record source. I am trying to resolve an outsanding issue from my previous post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771577/on-click-event-on-an-unbound-control-in-ms-access?rq=1.

Comment: What is `Screen.ActiveControl.Name` giving you?  Is it the name of the control you expect?